# SQL Query / Xml

Tags: sql, xml

I'm trying to query a table which has a column that contains straight xml data.  Within the query I'm querying columns that hold straight data (int, vchar etc) but I'm also querying the xml column.  In the xml column i want to grab a value within the xml and return null if it doesn't exist.  I have the following query that almost works but returns duplicates.  Need help!

I have my root xml CodeFiveReport then within it Properties and within that Property which has a serial number.  I'm trying to grab the serial number if it exists and displaying it.

```
select Distinct rs.Id
        , rs.CaseNumber
        , rs.StartDate
        , rs.[Status]
        , rs.PatrolDistrict
        , rs.PrimaryUnit
        , rs.Location
        , rs.ReportType
        , rs.IncidentType
        , rs.UserId
        , rs.UnitId
        , rs.UnitCode
        , rs.IsLocked
        , rs.LockedBy
        , rs.AgencyId
        , rl.ReportName
        , rl.ParentId
        , TempTable.Party.value('(SerialNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as SerialNumber
    from dbo.vw_ReportSummary rs OUTER APPLY Report.nodes('/CodeFiveReport/Properties/Property') AS TempTable(Party)
    left outer join dbo.ReportLookup rl on rs.Id = rl.Id
    where  rs.[Status] = 'Approved'  
    order by rs.Id
```

Comment: If DISTINCT returns duplicates, those aren't really duplicates - check your data!

Comment: The Serial Number being returned is different per result... all I need to know is if the xml for the particular record cotains ANY serial number, not all of them.  That's what I can't figure out how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to solve the problem

I changed `Report.nodes('/CodeFiveReport/Properties/Property')` to `Report.nodes('/CodeFiveReport/Properties')`

In turn I also changed my TempTable query to: `TempTable.Party.value('(Property/SerialNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as SerialNumber` and that seemed to fix the duplicates.

Thanks for your help everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing your exact database schema. Assuming that this is T-SQL: Have a look at CTE (common table expressions) and split your statement in two steps. That makes these kind of statements usually much simpler and often more efficient.